# Is it possible to add css for mobile in fandom wiki?

Tags: css, mobile, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, wikitext

The mobile version of the fandom wikis are very restricted, and actively strips away all style tags from html elements.

I tried to define styles in MediaWiki:Common.css and that works on desktop, but it does not apply on mobile.

I have also tried to add stuff in MediaWiki:Mobile.css which was actually existing initially with a comment saying:

```
/* All CSS here will be loaded for users of the mobile site */
```

But the styles I added here did not load either in the mobile theme.

Is it possible to apply any custom css that is applied in the mobile theme on a Fandom wiki page?

See example on this page:

[Animals (desktop)](https://root-land.fandom.com/wiki/Animals?useskin=fandomdesktop)

Here you see example of an animal image with a label text that is styled with CSS to look like a "shield":

[image: Rabbit on desktop]

For the [mobile version](https://root-land.fandom.com/wiki/Animals?useskin=fandommobile), this style does not have effect:

[image: Rabbit on mobile]
This shows the original image as is without css styling on the container that would cut it in a shield form, and the label text below also without css styling. When I look at the source in browser debugger tools, I see that the html is correct, and the css class names are added, but the style is not loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, Fandom prevented wiki admins from adding custom CSS (and JS) for the mobile skins. They preferred maintaing a plain and uniformal look for the mobile view.

However, a continious push from the community made them reconsider the policy, and on late 2022 they announced a proposed change, which took place in steps during the following months.

On April 22, 2023, Fandom [officially announced](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Jpearson/Everything_You_Need_to_Know_About_Mobile_CSS) that custom CSS for mobile is available for editing by local admins on all Fandom wikis, using `MediaWiki:FandomMobile.css`

As with any custom code, it has to follow Fandom's [Customization Policy](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/Help:Customization_policy).

It should be noted that *personal* custom CSS and JS for mobile were already available for a while by editing local user subpages. However *global personal* CSS and JS don't affect the mobile skin.